# Como deixar a imagem na frente do texto?

Tags: css

A imagem abaixo mostra que ao colocar o mouse sobre a imagem, ela fica maior com um SCALE via CSS (`transform: scale(3.05)`). Porém o conteúdo do site que vem abaixo fica sobre a imagem, alguém saberia dizer qual código CSS devo usar para colocar a imagem em primeiro plano, acima de qualquer conteúdo? Ou seja, a imagem deve ficar acima dos textos que vem abaixo dela.

[image]

Comment: Amigão, usa o z-index do css, descubra qual z-index da image abaixo e aplica um valor maior ou menos na div que vc quer deixar a frente.

Answer (score 2):

Coloca esse elemento com uma propriedade:

`z-index: 9999`;

Comment: Vale lembrar que o `z-index` só funciona para elementos posicionados

Comment: Esse com certeza é posicionado.